# query with group by

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I am trying and so far not succeeding in making a query with a group by-statement.

I have a table with different types of activities (tblExcursion) and a table with the planned (tblReservationDetail). In tblExcursion I have a column 'GroupName'. There are multiple activities under one GroupName (e.g. kayak, sailing, waterpolo is groupname Watersports).

Now I want to retrieve the number of participants per GroupName (not per activity/excursion!). But I am not getting there with .GroupBy() or group...by

This is the query where I use the activityname and not the groupname:

```
var vAllExcursions = (from oExcursion in clsApplication._oDBConnection.tblExcursions
                      select oExcursion).ToList();

foreach (tblExcursion EXitem in vAllExcursions)
{
    var vAllExcursionsPerType = (from oReservationDetail in clsApplication._oDBConnection.tblReservationDetails
                                         where oReservationDetail.StartTime.Date.Year == this.cboYear.getSelectedID()
                                         && oReservationDetail.StartTime.Date.Month == this.cboMonth.getSelectedID()
                                         && oReservationDetail.ExcursionID == EXitem.ID
                                         select oReservationDetail).ToList();
}

Here I fill my datagrid
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to group by the `GroupName` to get the groups:

```
var vAllExcursions = clsApplication._oDBConnection.tblExcursions
    .GroupBy(ex => ex.GroupName)
    .ToList();
```

Then in your inner loop, find any related reservations by checking if the `ExcursionID` matches any id in the list associated with the group:

```
foreach (var EXitemGroup in vAllExcursions)
{
    var excursionIds = EXitemGroup.Select (exg => exg.ID).ToArray();
    ...
        && excursionIds.Contains(oReservationDetail.ExcursionID)
    ...
}
```

Comment: I get error: Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementations of query operators except the Contains operator.

Comment: Ah. Yes I was testing with inline data lists, let me test with SQL backend.

Comment: As a courtesy to users taking the effort to answer your questions and for the benefit of future users of this site, please mark the answer that solves your question.  When you open the question, there is a large checkmark under the vote count that you can click on to mark this the answer, for instance.  Once you have done that here, do that to the rest of your questions and make it a habit going forward.  Thanks :)